# How to install wine on Linux on debain 64bit system?

Tags: linux, terminal, wine, gnome-terminal

[image]

I tried to install **wine** on my Linux but it fails with the above error message.

I've tried to fix it for hours without no luck. Any idea why does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install with aptitude: `sudo aptitude install winehq-stable` (`aptitude` will suggest resolutions to the problem) or just install first wine-stable then winehq-stable.

Comment: Oh My Gosh It actually Worked thank you so much <3